# Specify FolderId When Uploading a File on the Frontend

Tags: frontend-form

In a front-end form where I am uploading a file, I need to specify a specific subfolder. I can't do it in the cp dynamic field for reasons so I was hoping to use a hidden field to set the folderId. The folderId exists and each entry has a different folder. I have this code that works but I can't figure out the code, for example something like: folderId: 44

```
<form method="post">
 {{ csrfInput() }}
 {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
 {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '3') }}
 {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}
 {{ hiddenInput('entryId', entry.id) }}
 {{ hiddenInput('redirect', craft.app.request.absoluteUrl|hash) }}

    {% for relatedAssetId in entry.patientFiles.ids() %}
      {{ input(
          'hidden',
          'fields[patientFiles][]',
          relatedAssetId,
        ) }}
    {% endfor %}
          {{ input('file', 'fields[patientFiles][]', options={
             multiple: true,
          }) }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a specific folder using the Assets service:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-assets.html#public-methods

If you know all the necessary information when that template is parsed, the [findFolder](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-assets.html#method-findfolder) method might be useful but [ensureFolderByFullPathAndVolume](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-assets.html#method-ensurefolderbyfullpathandvolume) is probably more precise.

For example:

```
{{ hiddenInput( 'secret_folder_id', 
    craft.app.assets.ensureFolderByFullPathAndVolume($volumePath, $assetVolume) ) }}
```

Comment: Sorry, my request upon re-reading it might be vague. I have the folderId, the question is how tell the frontend form to make sure the asset gets uploaded specifically to that subfolder. I want something like {{ hiddenInput('folderId':44) }} but that does not work and the asset always just uploads to the parent volume, not the subfolder

Comment: Ok, I *think* I know what you mean. You could try changing the properties of the asset field, checking "Restrict assets to a single folder" and specifying the path to the subfolder you'd like things to save to.